# App is giving SIGABRT when running on already running simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, sigabrt

When I am running the application from XCode through the simulator for the first time its running fine. But when the application is running in the simulator and if I run again from the XCode the app is stuck at splash screen, and the app is giving SIGABRT crash. When I stop the build from XCode the app continues to run from the splash screen. What might be the issue?

Comment: But if I run after stopping the previous run its working fine. It only giving this crash only when I try to run when the same app is already running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Xcode 4.6.2 on OSX 10.8.4, try upgrading to Xcode 4.6.3 which was just released a few days ago. The 4.6.3 version has fixes for the random crashes and hangs that sometimes happens when debugging on the ios simulator.

Comment: Yes I am using XCode 4.6.2 and on OSX 10.8.4. May be this might be causing the issue. I will update and try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is XCode issue. Sometimes the bootstrap fails to register the application. Usually giving an error on console as

```
Couldn't register com.compname.yourapp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Solution

1. If running on device, switch off and restart device.
2. If running on simulator, restart your Mac.